# Redimension the first value of a multi-dimensional array in VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

There has to be a simpler way to do this.  I took the advice of one poster on this forum who said that I have to set my multidimensional array to a high number then redimension it to a lower number.  But in order to get it to the right number I have to run it through two loops where it seems like there has to be a simpler way to do things.  So I have the array ancestors which has several blanks in it which I'm trying to get rid of.  The second dimension will always be 2.  I first run it through a loop to determine the ubound of it. And I call that ancestors3. Then I run the ancestors3 array through a loop and populate the ancestors2 array.

```
For s = 1 To UBound(ancestors, 1)
temp_ancest = ancestors(s, 1)
If temp_ancest <> "" Then
    uu = uu + 1
    ReDim Preserve ancestors3(uu)
    ancestors3(uu) = temp_ancest
End If
Next

Dim ancestors2()
ReDim ancestors2(UBound(ancestors3), 2)

For s = 1 To UBound(ancestors3, 1)
temp_ancest = ancestors(s, 1)
temp_ancest2 = ancestors(s, 2)
If temp_ancest <> "" Then
    y = y + 1
    ancestors2(y, 1) = temp_ancest
    ancestors2(y, 2) = temp_ancest2
End If
Next
```

Comment: are u sure this code is giving you the desired output. the second loop doesn't make much sense.... also too many `Redim Preserve` executions (these are extremely inefficient). Could you show a Very Very simple example, like `ancestors(1,1) = "a1", ancestors(1,2) = "b1"`, etc. ---> and what results you want to see in `ancestors2(1,1)`, etc.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Please give an example for sample input and expected output. You may add that at the end of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question i think you want this:

1. you have a 2D array `ancestors` that may have some blank entries in the 1st dimension
2. you want a copy of `ancestors` without those blank rows, called `ancestors2`

Here is one way to do this.  See inline comments for explanation

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ancestors As Variant
    Dim ancestors2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim LB as long

    ' Populate ancestors as you see fit
    '...


    ' crate array ancestors2, same size as ancestors, but with dimensions flipped
    '  so we can redim it later
    ReDim ancestors2(LBound(ancestors, 2) To UBound(ancestors, 2), _
      LBound(ancestors, 1) To UBound(ancestors, 1))

    ' Loop ancestors array, copy non-blank items to ancestors2
    j = LBound(ancestors, 1)
    LB = LBound(ancestors, 1)
    For i = LBound(ancestors, 1) To UBound(ancestors, 1)
        If ancestors(i, 1) <> vbNullString Then
            ancestors2(LB, j) = ancestors(i, LB)
            ancestors2(LB + 1, j) = ancestors(i, LB + 1)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next

    ' Redim ancestors2 to match number of copied items
    ReDim Preserve ancestors2(LBound(ancestors2, 1) To UBound(ancestors2, 1), _
      LBound(ancestors2, 2) To j - 1)

    ' Transpose ancestors2 to restore flipped dimensions
    ancestors2 = Application.Transpose(ancestors2)
End Sub
```